# Directx Ray Tracing Dxr Support Application Issue

Tags: directx12

I have a question, I have source code that is old that was built in visual studio 2003 and It does not allow me to compile DirectX12 code in visual studio 2003 so my Attentions was to take my old game I built and update it to support dxr ray-tracing but my question is, Is it better to code my dxr support in a "dll" and just use run-time linking to call each function upon execution of the game process "executable" or just code it to the application itself and execute it. Cause, I really don't want to rewrite all my code in visual studio 2017 to be honest there is several lines of code "over 10,000" so yeah any advice Much Appreciated.

Comment: DXR requires working with Direct3D 12. If you are application is DirectX8 or DirectX9, the first step would be to modernize it to DirectX 12. As part of that you can update the code to VS 2017.

Comment: yeah, I really don't want to rewrite and modernize over 10,000 lines of code there has to be another method I can try.